# how do i store a static html page in android emulator and later on view it from WebView while running?

Tags: android, android-webview, assets

how do i store a static html page in android emulator and later on view it from WebView while running?

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way for accomplish your task is to use the assets folder:

- Create a toplevel folder named
  "assets"
- Put your static html files there

Load the html file with somethinh like this:

```
...
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourpage.html");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example on how to load a static page into a WebView:
http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/